# Event handling with WinRT for python

Tags: python, events, windows-runtime, python-asyncio, winrt-async

## The Task

I'm trying to make a tool that auto recognizes playback from a non Spotify source and pauses Spotify for the duration of the other audio. I've been using Microsoft's WinRT projection for Python (https://github.com/Microsoft/xlang/tree/master/src/package/pywinrt/projection). I can get the program to recognize audio sources and playback status but only from the moment the function was called. After that it stops updating.

## The Problem

My main problem is understanding how WinRT implemented event handling in Python. The windows docs talk about a "changed playback event" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.control.globalsystemmediatransportcontrolssession.playbackinfochanged?view=winrt-22000) but I can't find any clue to how this is accomplished in the Python projection of the API.

## Current State

Here is my code so far, any help is appreciated.

```
import asyncio
import time
from winrt.windows.media.control import \
    GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager as MediaManager
from winrt.windows.media.control import \
    GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSession as SessionMananger
from winrt.windows.media.control import \
    PlaybackInfoChangedEventArgs as PlaybackEventArgs

async def toggle_spotify():
    sessions = await MediaManager.request_async() #grab session manager instance

    all_sessions = sessions.get_sessions() #grab sequence of current instances
    for current_session in all_sessions: #iterate and grab desired instances
        if "chrome" in current_session.source_app_user_model_id.lower():
            chrome_info = current_session.get_playback_info()
        if "spotify" in current_session.source_app_user_model_id.lower():
            spotify_manager = current_session 
            spotify_info = current_session.get_playback_info()
    if chrome_info.playback_status == 4 and spotify_info.playback_status == 4: #status of 4 is playing, 5 is paused
        await spotify_manager.try_toggle_play_pause_async()
    elif chrome_info.playback_status == 5 and spotify_info.playback_status == 5:
        await spotify_manager.try_toggle_play_pause_async()
        # print(f"chrome playback status: {chrome_info.playback_status}")
        # print(f"chrome playback status: {spotify_info.playback_status}")
        # print("+++++++++++++++++")
        # time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #asyncio.run(get_media_info())
    while True: #mimicking event handling by looping
        asyncio.run(toggle_spotify())
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, FYI, I've started a community fork of PyWinRT and the `winrt` package at https://github.com/pywinrt and published a [winsdk](https://pypi.org/project/winsdk/) package on PyPI. This contains many, many fixes over the seemingly unmaintained `winrt` package, including fixing some serious problems like leaking a COM object on every `await` of an `_async()` method. The new `winsdk` package also includes type hints which make solving issues like this much easier.

The way event handlers are used is currently documented [here](https://github.com/pywinrt/pywinrt/blob/main/src/package/pywinrt/projection/readme.md#event-handlers).

So for this specific case, your code might look something like this:

```py
import asyncio

from winsdk.windows.media.control import (
    GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager as SessionManager,
    GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionPlaybackStatus as PlaybackStatus,
    SessionsChangedEventArgs,
)


async def update_sessions(manager: SessionManager) -> None:
    for session in manager.get_sessions():
        if "chrome" in session.source_app_user_model_id.lower():
            chrome_info = session.get_playback_info()
            if chrome_info.playback_status == PlaybackStatus.PLAYING:
                ...


def handle_sessions_changed(manager: SessionManager, args: SessionsChangedEventArgs) -> None:
    asyncio.create_task(update_sessions(manager))


async def main():
    manager = await SessionManager.request_async()

    # add callback to handle any future changes
    sessions_changed_token = manager.add_sessions_changed(handle_sessions_changed)

    try:
        # handle current state
        asyncio.create_task(update_sessions(manager))

        event = asyncio.Event()
        # wait forever - a real app would call event.set() to end the app
        await event.wait()
    finally:
        # remove the callback
        manager.remove_sessions_changed(sessions_changed_token)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

For some reason, the event doesn't actually seem to be firing, but a quick web search reveals that this is a common problem for the `GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.SesssionsChanged` and seems unrelated to the Python bindings.

Also note that `asyncio.create_task()` is only needed if `update_sessions()` actually awaits something, otherwise it could just be called directly.